# Should the [1984] tag be changed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

If I'm not mistaken, I was the one who originally created the [1984](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1984) tag, which has now been applied to more than a few questions. However, I'm wondering if I made a mistake, as I just realized the actual title of Orwell's novel is *Nineteen Eighty-Four*, spelled out. Personally, I don't think this is a huge issue, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four) states the book is "often published as 1984".

Thus, I'm against changing the name of the tag to the spelled out version, but I'd be fine if the spelled out version of the title was made a synonym to the actual tag we have now. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Done...........

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like a good time for a tag synonym.

I'd recommend making the [nineteen-eighty-four](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nineteen-eighty-four) tag and then getting the CMs to make [1984](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1984) a synonym. That way, if anyone tries to use just "1984", it will still get the appropriate tag but if the title is officially spelled out, that should be the primary tag.

Comment: I went with this logic, too.